# Initializer_list as argument to an array reference parameter in a not-template context

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, overload-resolution

My question concerns this very simple and short code where an overload resolution is attempted between two non-template functions accepting an array reference parameter. The question has been posted elsewhere, but in a template deduction context. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo ( const int (&x) [3] ) { std::cout << "3\n"; }
void foo ( const int (&x) [2] ) { std::cout << "2\n"; }

int main()
{
    foo({1,2,3});
}
```

g++ 4.8.3 compiles this code selecting the first function as (I suppose) the ONLY viable,
while clang 3.4 doesn't compile it, saying that the call to foo  is  ambiguous (why?).

Which compiler does the right thing?

clang doesn't compile the code even removing the second overload: it seems that an initializer_list is simply not accepted to initialize an array reference.

Is this buggy?

Comment: "clang doesn't compile the code even removing the second overload" -- It does for me (if the second overload is removed as you say), using clang 3.4.2, as long as `-std=c++11` is included in the command-line options. Which version and which invocation fails for you?

Comment: You're right: after removing the second overload I compiled the code forgetting the flag -std=c++11. Sorry for that.

Comment: Now I have defined a command alias to avoid such a mistake in future...

Answer (score 6):

I think that although GCC's behaviour is more useful, it's clang's behaviour that is correct for C++11:

> **13.3.3.1.5 List-initialization sequence [over.ics.list]**
>
> 2 If the parameter type is `std::initializer_list<X>` or "array of `X`" and all the elements of the initializer list can be implicitly converted to `X`, the implicit conversion sequence is the worst conversion necessary to convert an element of the list to `X`.

This conversion sequence pays no attention to the array length. Both function overloads give an implicit conversion sequence that is an identity conversion: both take a reference to an array of `int`, and each element in the function argument is an `int`.

Overload resolution then sees two identity conversions, and although the standard does have a few exceptions for resolving conflicts on conversions of equal rank, there is none that pays attention to the array's length:

> **13.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences [over.ics.rank]**
>
> 3 Two implicit conversion sequences of the same form are indistinguishable conversion sequences unless one of the following rules applies:

followed by a list that does not mention arrays at all.

Jonathan Wakely points out that this has since changed. Your question is exactly what prompted that change, and the corresponding DR is [#1307](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1307). In C++14, your code is valid, but not in C++11.

Comment: The parameter type is not `std::initializer_list` though, and the current working paper handles arrays and `initializer_list` separately in different paragraphs, specifically mentioning the array length: _"Otherwise, if the parameter type is “array of N X”, if the initializer list has exactly N elements or if it has
fewer than N elements and X is default-constructible, and if all the elements of the initializer list can be implicitly converted to X, the implicit conversion sequence is the worst conversion necessary to convert an element of the list to X."_

Comment: @JonathanWakely It says "`std::initializer_list<X>` or "array of `X`", and the parameter type is an array. I'll check the wording of more recent papers.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Heh, I had just found that myself too. :)

Answer (score 4):

[DR 1232](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1232) changed C++11 to allow calling functions with reference-to-array parameters from an initializer list. (The changes to the working paper are shown in [N3262](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1232).) All the compilers tested implement that rule.

[DR1307](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1307) then changed the same wording again to resolve the ambiguity you've discovered. Your code is accepted by GCC and EDG compilers, so I assume Clang does not implement that DR yet.

It's interesting to note that even after that DR was resolved, `foo({1, 2})` is still ambiguous, and rejected by all compilers. The reason is that `{1, 2}` can bind to the `const int(&)[2]` parameter (obviously) but it can also bind to the `const int(&)[3]` parameter because `int` is default-constructible, so it means the same as `{1, 2, int()}` i.e. `{1, 2, 0}`

Comment: "`foo({1, 2})` is still ambiguous" -- Are you sure? Doesn't "List-initialization sequence L1 is a better conversion sequence than list-initialization sequence L2 if ...  L1 converts to type “array of N1 T,” L2 converts to type “array of N2 T”, and N1 is smaller than N2." resolve that in favour of the `const int(&)[2]` overload?